# html2canvas save and name n images locally

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, automation, html2canvas

#### Specifications:

- `html2canvas` v1.0.0-alpha.12 ([available here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js))
- Google Chrome 66.0.3359.181
- Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

#### Issue:

Deepest apologies if this has already been answered—I'm a total novice with JS and online solutions for saving canvasses as images locally haven't quite seemed to work for me.

I have HTML featuring JS for randomization; each reload of the page can represent a "realization" of randomization. I'd like to generate n realizations of the HTML and save each as an image (with automatic sequential naming; e.g.,  if n=5000, `img_0001.png`, `img_0002.png`, ..., `img_4999.png`, `img_5000.png`).

Can anyone recommend a fix? So far, the only thing I've had success with has been to generate an on-screen .png with the below code (and then to "Save As ..." manually):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/baron1/Dropbox/github/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Reference [`html2canvas`](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js) link.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem, saves others time on searching for it.

Comment: Absolutely. I copy/pasted this from the `html2canvas` GitHub, which I decided wasn't the proper venue, but in my haste (and after many hours of travel between Tokyo and New York) I forgot to add in those particulars! Anyway, I very much appreciate the nudge!